# How to Stub a module in Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm trying to stub a module using Cypress. Here's what I've tried so far, but is not working.

This is the short version of my component/page

```js
// SomeComponent.jsx

import { useSomething } from './useSomething'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  // useSomething is a custom hook
  const { data, error } = useSomething()

  const renderData = () => {
    // map the data into an array of JSX elements
    return data.map(...)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {renderData()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SomeComponent
```

Here's how my custom hook looks like

```js
// useSomething.js

import { useState } from 'react'
import { getData } from './db'

export const useSomething = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [error, setError] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(data => {
      setData(data)
    }).catch(err => {
      setError(error)
    })

    // ... some other unrelated code here
  }, [])

  return { data, error }
}
```

Here's how getData looks like

```js
// getData.js

export const getData = () => {
  const data = // some API call from external services

  return data
}
```

The method is exposed via db.js (actually db/index.js)

```js
// db.js

export * from './getData'
```

I'm trying to stub the getData.js to make the e2e test more consistent. Here's what I did.

```js
// something.spec.js

// I'm writing @src just to keep the code sample here short, it's the same file as the db.js I write above
import * as db from '@src/db'

...

// this is how I try to do the stubbing
cy.stub(db, 'getData').resolves(something)

...
```

The stubbing above doesn't work. The API call to the external service is still happening when running the test. The documentation itself leads me to deduce that I should write it this way, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose `db` on the window

```js
// useSomething.js

import { useState } from 'react'
import * as db from './db'

const { getData } = db;

if (window.Cypress) {     // only when testing
  window.db = db;
}
```

and in the test

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win.db, 'getData').resolves(something);
})
```

Or use [intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) to stub the API call.