# Cypress stub out loadStripe

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments, cypress

I'm having some trouble stub'ing out Stripe from my tests

> CartCheckoutButton.ts

```js
import React from 'react'
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'

import useCart from '~/state/CartContext'
import styles from './CartCheckoutButton.module.scss'

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)

const CartCheckoutButton = ({}: TCartCheckoutButtonProps) => {
  const { cartItems } = useCart()

  const handleCheckOutOnClick = async (event) => {
    const { sessionId } = await fetch('/api/checkout/session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ cartItems }),
    }).then((res) => res.json())

    const stripe = await stripePromise
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId,
    })

    if (error) {
      // TODO: Show some error message
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <button onClick={handleCheckOutOnClick} disabled={cartItems.length == 0}>
        CHECKOUT
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CartCheckoutButton
```

> EndUserExperience.spec.js

```js
import * as stripeJS from '@stripe/stripe-js'

describe('End user experience', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')

    cy.stub(stripeJS, 'loadStripe').resolves(
      new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve({
          redirectToCheckout({ sessionId }) {
            console.log(`redirectToCheckout called with sessionId: ${sessionId}`)
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              resolve({ error: true })
            })
          },
        })
      })
    )
  })

  it('Orders some dishes and makes a checkout', () => {
    console.log('working on it')
  })
})
```

When I click around it still redirects me. So the stub did not seem to kick in..

## Update II

Trying out the following solution suggested by @RichardMatsen

```
import React from 'react'
import * as stripeModule from '@stripe/stripe-js'

import useCart from '~/state/CartContext'
import styles from './CartCheckoutButton.module.scss'

const stripePublishableKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

const CartCheckoutButton = ({}: TCartCheckoutButtonProps) => {
  const { cartItems } = useCart()

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565714/cypress-stub-out-loadstripe
  const stripePromise = React.useCallback(() => {
    window['stripeModule'] = stripeModule
    return stripeModule.loadStripe(stripePublishableKey)
  }, [stripeModule, stripePublishableKey])

  const handleCheckOutOnClick = async (event) => {
    const { sessionId } = await fetch('/api/checkout/session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ cartItems }),
    }).then((res) => res.json())

    const stripe = await stripePromise()
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId,
    })

    if (error) {
      // TODO: Show some error message
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <button onClick={handleCheckOutOnClick} disabled={cartItems.length == 0}>
        TILL KASSAN
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CartCheckoutButton
```

> test.spec.js

```
describe('End user experience', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')

    cy.window().then((win) => {
      console.log(win)
      cy.stub(win.stripeModule, 'loadStripe').resolves(
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          resolve({
            redirectToCheckout({ sessionId }) {
              console.log(`redirectToCheckout called with sessionId: ${sessionId}`)
              return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve({ error: true })
              })
            },
          })
        })
      )
    })

    cy.intercept('GET', /.*stripe.*/, (req) => {
      req.redirect('http://localhost:3000/checkout/success')
    })
  })

  it('Orders some dishes and makes a checkout', () => {
    console.log('working on it')
  })
})
```

But it still redirect me and display an error

```
Trying to stub property 'loadStripe' of undefined
```

Comment: Re update: You can't await `cy.window()`, it has a `.then()` method but it's not a promise.

Comment: `useEffect` is not needed to set the stripeModule reference, but it should be used to defer the call to `stripeModule.loadStripe` - see below

Comment: "Trying to stub property 'loadStripe' of undefined" occurs because you are setting `window.stripeModule` too late. It should be done right after the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't stub a method in the app by importing it's module in the test, it looks like you get a different "instance".

Please see this recent question [How to Stub a module in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67478383/4716245), an approach that works is to pass the instance to be stubbed via `window`.

**CartCheckoutButton.ts**

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import * as stripeModule from '@stripe/stripe-js';

if (process.browser) {                  // this check needed for NextJS SSR
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.stripeModule = stripeModule;
  }
}

// const stripePromise = loadStripe(...)  // need to defer this call
                                          // from load time to runtime
                                          // see useCallback below

// Maybe put this outside the React function, 
// since dependencies shouldn't have property references
const stripeKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;



const CartCheckoutButton = ({}: TCartCheckoutButtonProps) => {

   const stripePromise = useCallback(() => {
     return stripeModule.loadStripe(stripeKey);
   }, [stripeModule, stripeKey]);
```

**EndUserExperience.spec.js**

```js
beforeEach(() => {

  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
    .then(win => {                      // wait for app to initialize

      const stripeModule = win.stripeModule;
      cy.stub(stripeModule, 'loadStripe').resolves(...

    })
```

---

### Reproducable example

**Build the default Next app**

```
npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/tree/master/learn-starter"
```

**Add stripeModule reference and useCallback() to /pages/index.js**

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import * as stripeModule from '@stripe/stripe-js';

import Head from 'next/head'

if (process.browser) {
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.stripeModule = stripeModule; 
  }
}

const stripeKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;

export default function Home() {

  const stripePromise = useCallback(() => {
    return stripeModule.loadStripe(stripeKey);
  }, [stripeModule, stripeKey]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
    ...
```

**Add a basic test**

```
it('stubs loadStripe', () => {

  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/').then(win => {
    const stripeModule = win.stripeModule;
    cy.stub(stripeModule, 'loadStripe').resolves(
      console.log('Hello from stubbed loadStripe')
    )
  })
})
```

**Build, start, test**

```
yarn build
yarn start
yarn cypress open
```

The message from `cy.stub()` is printed to the console.

Comment: It makes sense that I'm not catching the correct instance. But your suggestion does not seem to work (plz see updated question)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and trying to help me out. Your suggestion makes sense but I just can't get it to work (make a second update). I even tried to use the no ssr option by `next/dynamic`

Comment: Setting the `stripeModule` reference inside the hook is most likely doing it after the test has tried to use it (hence `undefined`). You should get better results setting it outside the React component.

Comment: When I do that it throws `cy.visit() failed trying to load: http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: hmm.. when using the `dynamic` it does not seem to redirect

Comment: For NextJS  use `if (process.browser) {` to avoid SSR problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Got it working most of the way. I'm stubing out the other calls to stripe and denouncing them to a cy.visit("/checkout/success")  - however it does not navigate to it